# Querying when there is a dash in json key name

Tags: couchdb

I have a doc:

```
{
   "_id": "0ccbe004e9b69bb7e1b7f4b6920024fb",
   "_rev": "1-948798db6b779ca01d67a2e72c07062c",
   "key": "back_text",
   "value": "back",
   "value-de-DE": "zurück"
}
```

This works:

```
function(doc) {
  emit('data', {key:doc.key, value:doc.value});
}
```

Understandably this doesn't work (returns zero results):

```
function(doc) {
  emit('data', {key:doc.key, value:doc.value-de-DE});
}
```

How can I query it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
function(doc) {
  emit('data', {key:doc.key, value:doc['value-de-DE']});
}
```